# Connecting to MS SQL Server on Linux in php

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

```
$server = 'x.x.x.x\SQLEXPRESS'; 
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');


if (!$link)
 {

    die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');

}
else
{
echo "Connected!";
}
```

It works on windows operating system. but when run linux show "Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL"
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to

1.Enable the loading of mssql libraries in php.ini.

2.Check for status of services

3.And also check the php log file to know exactly what is the error.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
flush();
```

You can add this piece of code in starting of your .php file, and check what is the exact error.

thanks

Comment: get message :Unable to connect to server

Comment: This is a doubt only.have you installed the TDS Driver?   If not , check out this "http://www.freetds.org/"  This     http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php#81149 can give you some info on this.